# Delete div if no ajax info about id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i got this code

```
function get_players()
{
 $.ajax({   
    type:   "POST",
    url:    "get_players.php",   
    dataType: "html",  
    success:  function(data) {
        var str = data;
    var chars = str.split("<br />");
    for(var i = chars.length - 1; i >= 0 ;i-- ) {
     chars[i] = chars[i].split('/');
     var o = document.getElementById(chars[i][0]);
     var aimt = i;
     if (!o) {
      if (aimt!=chars.length -1) {
       $('#gracze').html('<div id="'+chars[aimt][0]+'" class="char"><div id="char_name" style="left:-'+(((chars[aimt][3].length*9)/2)-16)+'px;width:'+(chars[aimt][3].length*9)+'px;">'+chars[aimt][3]+'</div></div>'+$('#gracze').html());
       $('#'+chars[aimt][0]).css("top", chars[aimt][2]*32-16+"px");
       $('#'+chars[aimt][0]).css("left", chars[aimt][1]*32+"px");
       $('#'+chars[aimt][0]).css("z-index", chars[aimt][2]+1);
      }
     } else {
      $('#'+chars[aimt][0]).animate({
       "top": chars[aimt][2]*32-16+"px", "left": chars[aimt][1]*32+"px"
      }, { duration: 300});
      //$('#'+chars[aimt][0]).css("top", chars[aimt][1]*32-16+"px");
      //$('#'+chars[aimt][0]).css("left", chars[aimt][2]*32+"px");
      $('#'+chars[aimt][0]).css("z-index", chars[aimt][2]);
     }
    }
  }});
 setTimeout("get_players();", 300);
}
```

which receives players from this

```
5/7/13/GodFather
6/7/10/dsfsf
7/8/13/fdsf
```

and i want to ask how to delete div if there's no info about user

Comment: What would a "no info" response look like?

Comment: @Patrick Beardmore no info about player will display nothing it will skip to next one it's showing only online players

Comment: And what would a "no info" response from the php script look like? Would it be /// then a new line?

Comment: if there's no players on map then the file is blank and js code is not running up thanks to that if (!o) {

Comment: Holly cow, this code needs optimization...

Comment: Your testcase has no `<div>`, you did not explain what steps you have taken so far to achieve your goal, and you didn't even bother to punctuate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>As you don't know which div elements to remove, the only way is removing them all then adding those you get from the AJAX response.</strike>

To remove them all, use the class that you already have:

```
$(".char").remove();
```

Add this line to the `success` function, before iterating over the lines.

OK, you can save the ID values returned by the AJAX call in array then remove any that does not exist in the array. Revised function code:

```
success:  function(data) {
    var str = data;
    var chars = str.split("<br />");
    var arrDivIDs = new Array();
    for(var i = chars.length - 1; i >= 0 ;i-- ) {
        chars[i] = chars[i].split('/');
        arrDivIDs[chars[i][0]] = true;
        var o = document.getElementById(chars[i][0]);
        var aimt = i;
        if (!o) {
            if (aimt!=chars.length -1) {
                $('#gracze').html('<div id="'+chars[aimt][0]+'" class="char"><div id="char_name" style="left:-'+(((chars[aimt][3].length*9)/2)-16)+'px;width:'+(chars[aimt][3].length*9)+'px;">'+chars[aimt][3]+'</div></div>'+$('#gracze').html());
                $('#'+chars[aimt][0]).css("top", chars[aimt][2]*32-16+"px");
                $('#'+chars[aimt][0]).css("left", chars[aimt][1]*32+"px");
                $('#'+chars[aimt][0]).css("z-index", chars[aimt][2]+1);
            }
        } else {
            $('#'+chars[aimt][0]).animate({
                "top": chars[aimt][2]*32-16+"px", "left": chars[aimt][1]*32+"px"
            }, { duration: 300});
            $('#'+chars[aimt][0]).css("z-index", chars[aimt][2]);
        }
    }

    $(".char").each(function(index) {
        if (!arrDivIDs[$(this).attr("id")])
            $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: i can't do that because these div's are moving :/

Comment: @Sonny cheers, now I advice you to improve the code, I've started doing it but realized there's no point as you won't learn anything if I give it on silver plate.. start by taking things like `chars[aimt][0]` out into local variables then use those variables instead of repeatedly reading from the array. This will make wonders to the readability of the code plus make it look much more possessional. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.remove()` http://api.jquery.com/remove/

**EDIT**

Where you have the check to see whether there is any data coming back (assume `var o`) you can do this:

```
o.remove();
```

**EDIT 2**

You can use variables in jQuery to select the id:

```
$("#" + chars[i][0]).remove();
```

Comment: i need to destroy the div only if there's no info that's the point

Comment: I think you need to edit your question. Try to specify what a normal response would look like (including HTML) and what a failed response would look like (again including HTML). This way we can find out exactly what id to use remove the div.